# Autorização de empresa para submissão de app

Tags: ios

Preciso submeter um aplicativo a loja da Apple, que fiz como freelancer para uma empresa. O aplicativo possui fotos e descrições da empresa e de seus clientes.

Me foi dito que preciso mandar, junto com o app, uma autorização da empresa. Alguém sabe o modelo dessa autorização? Sabem se tenho que mandar no momento que o app será submetido, por fax ou algo do tipo?

Além da regra da apple dizer:
"Apps may not use protected third party material such as trademarks, copyrights, patents or violate 3rd party terms of use. Authorization to use such material must be provided upon request"

Falei com uma pessoa que teve que mandar uma autorização, mas não tem mais acesso a ela e não lembra.

Comment: Ainda não sei o que pensar sobre esta pergunta. Estamos discutindo o que faz parte do nosso foco em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic. Ela não parece se encaixar em nenhum item proposto. Mas talvez seja apenas porque ainda não tinha aparecido um caso assim. Qualquer um com reputação mínima pode propor perguntas burocráticas sobre desenvolvimento de software e votar em todos os itens concordando ou discordando.

Comment: A solução mais simples seria a empresa ter uma conta dela. Se no futuro a empresa precisar alterar o aplicativo e você não puder fazer, como é que fica?

Comment: Acho que essa não seria a solução mais simples já que criar uma conta empresa é bem mais complicado. E isso não vem ao caso, a conta é individual e preciso saber o modelo para enviar a apple com a autorização da empresa.

Comment: @bigown, isso beira uma questão legal, não? Se sim, acho que já foi concordado que está fora do escopo...

Comment: É perfeitamente legal esse tipo de coisa, só preciso da autorização da empresa. Acho que o assunto se enquadra mais em dúvidas quanto a submissão de aplicativos para apple store.

Comment: Creio ser válida, por estar relacionada diretamente com a programação para dispositivos móveis. O processo seria programar, testar e fazer o deploy na AppStore, e esta pergunta se refere à este último passo.

Comment: A regra da Apple diz "upon request", dando a entender eles vão pedir a autorização se necessário (e provavelmente indicar um modelo, ou então o modelo não é importante).

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu estava com medo do app ser rejeitado caso eu não mandasse e, como tenho pouco tempo, queria saber se alguém tinha já feito isso antes de começar o processo de enviar. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Eu respondi com base no que você disse na pergunta, nunca passei por isso. Mas parece que ninguém aqui sabe, acho que você devia consultar a Apple.

Comment: Seria muito bom deixar aberta essa pergunta porque não é de programação, mas é sobre o deploy de aplicativo para clientes que, sem ele não faz sentido programar para iOS. E essa questão é bem relevante. Vamos discutir isso no meta? http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/fechamento-devemos-ter-em-descontextualizada-outros-e-publicacao-em-app-stor

Comment: @rdprado você poderia postar o seu "edit" como a resposta da pergunta, e inclusive aceitar ela como correta (já que você fez e funcionou)

Comment: @woliveirajr certo, a pergunta havia sido encerrada pelos moderadores, então eu editei a pergunta. Agora já da pra colocar como resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- já mandei o app e foi aceito sem me pedirem nada, demorou uns 5 dias para ser aprovado.
- no processo de update do app para a versão 1.1 me foi perguntado pela Apple se eu exibia conteúdo de terceiros e respondi que sim. Foi perguntado se eu tinha autorização para isso e também respondi que sim, pois realmente tenho. Não precisei até hoje mandar nada